# I remember an english word (but cannot find it), which means to encircle a person by other (non-friendly) persons

Tags: expressions

It has a meaning of

- surround (by unfriendly persons)
- encircle (by unfriendly persons)
- usher
- corner
- hassle
- crowd
- sandwich (a person)
- accompany

Help!
How can I find this next time? I tried thesaurus but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Jostle? Hustle? Give someone the bum's rush? Oust? Eject? Kick, boot or throw someone out? None of these imply encircling though.

Comment: Here's a [more comprehensive thesaurus](https://onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=surround), it offers many worthless alternatives too, but it will always find your word if you try a couple of words close to the meaning you are after. I might suggest [beleaguer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beleaguer) myself, but it's just one of the choices.

Comment: *Gang up on someone*.

Answer (score 1):

Besiege.  This has a military overtone, but it does mean what  you are saying.

Comment: "Beset" is a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

**To envelop**  might be what you are thinking of. The etymology is the military strategy of attacking / defeating the enemy's flanks, and then surrounding the entire enemy formation (think the German 6th Army in Stalingrad) thus denying them re-supply and a means of retreat.

That verb can of course be used metaphorically, or be used more generally to mean *plunge something into complete darkness*.

Answer (score 0):

There's also *gherao*, which comes from the Hindi word *gherna* meaning *to surround*. The Oxford English Dictionary says:

> A form of harassment in labour disputes in India and Pakistan, whereby
>   workers detain their employers or managers on the premises, refusing
>   to let them depart until their claims are granted. Hence as v.
>   transitive, **to detain (a person) in this manner**.

Admittedly not a frequently used word but not overly opaque, as the OED goes on to explain:

> These words are not commonly found in general text types like novels
>   and newspapers, but at the same they are not overly opaque or obscure.
>   Nouns include ebullition and merengue, and examples of adjectives are
>   amortizable, prelapsarian...

Comment: CED adds the caveat 'Indian English'.

Answer (score 0):

Though tangentially synonymous with "surround" I am positive you are looking for the word:

**"Flank"**

> transitive verb
>
> **1a:** to be situated at the side of especially : to be situated on both sides of a road flanked with linden trees **b:** to place something on each side of
>
> **2:** to protect a flank of
>
> **3:** to attack or threaten the flank of (as a body of troops)
>
> (merriam-webster)

Though its official definition is a bit off the mark (which is a possible why you were not able to find it in a thesaurus), when used in context I believe this is the word.

"They **flanked** us on both sides."  [to sandwich]
"We were out maneuvered and out **flanked**." [in essence to be surrounded] "To my left **flank** my horse, to my right **flank** the sea" [Flank in this case means side, but could be mistaken for "accompany"] "The squad was **flanked** from the north, forcing them south."  [could be mistaken for "usher"] "Frank **flanked** the guard distracting him with his loud outbursts while his wife snuck past stealing the sacks of cash..." [could be mistaken for "hassle"]

**Flank** implies tactics and therefore attacking or in your case unfriendly people/enemies/combatants.

I hope this is the word and if not at least steers you closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Just watched a movie and the word was used:

**accost**

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/accost?s=t)

I remember its meaning as accompany/surround somebody against his will, which seems to be not correct...

Answer (score -4):

A popular expression, **Fish out of water**, means

> someone who is uncomfortable in a specific situation.

Vague, but its usage mostly conforms to people/ambience around the person.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-fish-out-of-water

Comment: I don't think *fish out of water* implies anything about being surrounded, or of unfriendly people doing the surrounding.

Comment: @nnnnnn Please check the referenced link before piping in. Read the example in the link. Baseless comments are unwelcome here.

Comment: I did, not that I needed to given how common the expression is. The example in the link does not say or imply anything about being encircled. It *could* apply in a situation with unfriendly people, but it doesn't inherently imply that and is often used for situations involving friendly people.

Comment: @nnnnnn Have you found an expression that is mot juste to the action in question? I would like to hear it. If you have an answer, feel free to put it forth. Do not dissuade others from doing so. :)

Comment: I thought that referred to a fish who had run out of Perrier!